# How can I remove the duplicates in a column of a 2D list and return the result as another list?

Tags: python

I read some data from a file. Each line of the file contains 10 numbers and I save all the lines in a 2 dimensional list.

```
data = []
with open(args.input, 'r') as f:
   for line in itertools.islice(f, 0, None):
    items = line.split()[1:]
    data.append(items)
```

Now I want to remove the duplicates of the first column in this 2d list and return the results as a list.

Is there some function that can do this or should I implement it myself?

thank you in advance!

**edit after comment by 
[Tichodroma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1907906/tichodroma):**

Sample input:

```
1 2 3 1 1 9 9 9 9 9
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
2 3 3 4 3 3 2 3 4 3
```

first column contains `[1 1 2 3 2]`

I want `[1 2 3]`

the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Please include a sample of the input and the desired output for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = """1 2 3 1 1 9 9 9 9 9
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
2 3 3 4 3 3 2 3 4 3"""

col1 = [line.split()[0] for line in data.splitlines()]
# col1 == ['1', '1', '2', '3', '2']

print(set(col1))
```

Output:

```
{'1', '2', '3'}
```

Comment: col1 = set([line.split()[0] for line in data.splitlines()])

Comment: @VincentBeltman Sure, but for educationals purpose, let's do it in two steps.

Comment: that was fast, thanks!
The equivallent for lists would probably be:
`N = set([line[0] for line in data])`